# FFMPEG Replacing black color fragments with alpha channel transparency

Tags: ffmpeg

I have `file.mov` video. It has a lot of blank black color fragments that have different durations.

I need to replace black color fragments that show up for more than 5 seconds with transparency. Is that possible to add some alpha channel for that purpose?

**Comment to Mulvya's answer:**

Amazing solution. With #2 section everything ok.

With #1 section I created this code:

```
output=$(ffprobe -f lavfi -i "movie=file.mov,blackdetect=d=3.5" -show_entries tags=lavfi.black_start,lavfi.black_end -of compact=p=0 -v 0|awk '!/^$/')
echo $output
```

using `awk '!/^$/'` to remove empty lines.

Here is the output I get:

[image: output]

`tag:lavfi.black_start` repeats with same value several times, not having right structure with closing `tag:lavfi.black_end`

If I change `blackdetect=d=3.5` to other value, for exaple `d=10`, it outputs the same result as `d=3.5`. How could I solve this issue having right `tag:lavfi.black_start`,`tag:lavfi.black_end` synthax with correct grepping `d=` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1** Run blackdetect to identify fragments

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i "movie=file.mov,blackdetect=d=3.5" -show_entries tags=lavfi.black_start,lavfi.black_end -of compact=p=0 -v 0
```

**Edit**: Due to a quirk in the filter, one has to use ffmpeg to get this data

The command below saves the data to a text file.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i movie=file.mov,blackdetect=d=3.5,metadata=print:file=- -f null - -hide_banner -v 0 | grep lavfi > times.txt
```

This will print a set of timecodes of black segments lasting atleast 3.5 seconds.

**#2** Add alpha and change alpha of fragments to 0

```
ffmpeg -i file.mov -vf format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0:enable='between(t,12.4,16.1)+between(t,55.1,60.0)+between(t,62.9,69.2)' -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 10 -b:v 0 out.mkv
```

In each between expression is the start time and end time of a black fragment, in seconds.

If you want to save the result to file, you'll need to pick a codec which supports alpha, like the one in the above command. If your file already has alpha, skip the format filter.

Comment: I've updated question with one issue regarding #1 section. Please reply me.

Comment: Can you share the file? Cut a small portion if it's too large: `ffmpeg -i in.mov -c copy -t 25 sample.mov`?

Comment: Here is it: https://toolsq.com/files/imagine.mov I only forgot that on 5th second on right top corner appears application logo, maybe it's issue? Logo is not needed, in other scripts I cropped it with - "[1:v]crop=iw:0.50*ih,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS$DIFF/TB, \"

Comment: Works with ffmpeg: `ffmpeg -i imagine.mov -vf blackdetect=d=3.5 -f null -`. I'm just testing filter logging. You'll have to apply crop to get correct results.

Comment: Thanks, it works correct. If not hard, could you tell me how to save ffmpeg output into text file or grep only lines containing word "blackdetect"? Have a Happy New Year!