# Video with transparent back

Tags: video, transparency, webm, apng

I’m creating a project for the browser on a Samsung info screen (55”) and I have to show different videos with transparent backgrounds (e.g. smoke) over text. I’ve tried with a webm format but the browser only shows the mask, not the actual movie. I tried with an animated png (apng) but performance is bad. I need your help. What other possibilities do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You may create WebM video file with alpha channel using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) in command line.

I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040320/ffmpeg-replacing-black-color-fragments-with-alpha-channel-transparency).

The following command (for example), generates synthetic video with 70% transparency:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=5:size=320x240:rate=1 -vf format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.3' -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 10 -b:v 0 vid.webm
```

The sample is "self contained" (not required an input video file), but simplistic.
Playing the video file `vid.webm` in a browser, shows that there is transparency.

Comment: Hi Rotem, thanks for suggesting the WebM format, I already tried it with the traditional video embed, which did not work. So I don't think this will have any effect.

Comment: I have no experience with embedding video. I recommend you to try using `FFmpeg` - it's very simple to execute the command line I posted. You wrote "browser only shows the mask". There is a chance that the mask causes the problem, and not the video. I suggest you to first try it without a mask. In case you like to get more specific solution, you need to post a question that reproduces the problem. If not `WebM` and not `apng`, what are you looking for?